# How to submit multiple forms with jquery in chrome? (works in firefox)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am using the following code to submit 2 forms in jquery and it works, but it does not work in chrome:

```
$('.set').click(function(event) {
    $("#date").submit();
    $("#time").submit();
});
```

I even tried event.prevent and a delay, but I think chrome just stops the script after the first submit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome and IE only the last will execute, first being discarded. The browser detects this as both requests are sent within one timestamp in your code above, and discards all except last submit.

You can use one single method (controller) on server side and execute both requests. Also, you can first submit call through ajax. You can call ajax in your click function and in success part submit second form. https://jsfiddle.net/f3gwbnp1/

```
$.ajax({
          url: $("#date").attr("action"),
          data: $("#date").serialize(),
          method: 'POST',
          success: function (result) {
               $("#time").submit();
          }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain the ajax bit?